# Is there a way to reorganize all my repeated VBoxes into a custom JavaFX tag?

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, fxml

TL;DR is at the bottom.

I am building a Weather App in JavaFX and the set up I am using is to have 5 `VBoxes` displayed horizontally in a `HBox` that represent 5 days of weather forecast data. The problem is that all these `VBoxes` are virtually identical except for the actual data displayed inside them.

For example all have a `Label` for the date, an `ImageView` for the weather icon (cloudy, sunny, rainy ect.), a `Label` for the temperature ect. This makes my `Controller` class have A LOT of `@FXML` annotated Labels and Buttons, ImageVeiws, everything in multiples of 5.

Is there a way to organize all my elements in a custom tag called `WeatherBox` which would pretty much be a `VBox` that would house all the components for me? Instead of everything being repeated 5 times in my `Controller` class I would just have 5 `WeatherBoxes`. I've looked at some other questions extending `Vboxes` and `HBoxes` and I don't feel like I am getting the idea (or the problem they are addressing is fundamentally different). They all suggest making the `WeatherBox` class a `Controller` class with it's own `FXML` file and I am not sure how I would tie that all into my main `fxml` file that the `WeatherBox` tags would sit in.

Extending `VBox` does seem like the way to go but I don't understand how to do it properly and how to use it to solve my issue. Does anyone have some suggestions?

TL;DR I am building a weather app and I have 5 `VBoxes` that are all pretty much identical. They all have child Labels and ImageViews and what not. Its making my `Controller class` look ridiculous because there is 5 of everything (Not DRY at all). Can I/How do I reorganize everything into a custom tag extending `VBox` that that I can drop into my `FXML` that will have all the `Labels`, `Buttons` and `ImageViews` already built in?

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import sample.datamodel.DataUtils;
import sample.datamodel.Location;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Optional;

public class Controller {

@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;
@FXML
private VBox forecast1;
@FXML
private VBox forecast2;
@FXML
private VBox forecast3;
@FXML
private VBox forecast4;
@FXML
private VBox forecast5;
@FXML
private Label date1;
@FXML
private Label date2;
@FXML
private Label date3;
@FXML
private Label date4;
@FXML
private Label date5;
@FXML
private Label description1;
@FXML
private Label description2;
@FXML
private Label description3;
@FXML
private Label description4;
@FXML
private Label description5;
@FXML
private Label percipitation1;
@FXML
private Label percipitation2;
@FXML
private Label percipitation3;
@FXML
private Label percipitation4;
@FXML
private Label percipitation5;
@FXML
private Label temperature1;
@FXML
private Label temperature2;
@FXML
private Label temperature3;
@FXML
private Label temperature4;
@FXML
private Label temperature5;
@FXML
private ImageView img1;
@FXML
private ImageView img2;
@FXML
private ImageView img3;
@FXML
private ImageView img4;
@FXML
private ImageView img5;
@FXML
private Button details1;
@FXML
private Button details2;
@FXML
private Button details3;
@FXML
private Button details4;
@FXML
private Button details5;
@FXML
private Button otherLocsButton;
@FXML
private Button todaysWeatherButton;
@FXML
private Button fiveDayButton;
@FXML
private Button refreshButton;
@FXML
private ListView<Location> locListView;

public void initialize() {
    locListView.setItems(DataUtils.getInstance().getLocations());
    locListView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    fiveDayButton.fire();
}

@FXML
public void refresh() {
    Location location = locListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    location.updateWeather();
    fiveDayForecast();

}

@FXML
public void fiveDayForecast() {
    Location location = locListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    location.updateWeather();
    Location.Day[] days = location.getDays();
    Location.Weather weather;
    VBox[] wthrPanes = {forecast1, forecast2, forecast3, forecast4, forecast5};
    Label[] dates = {date1, date2, date3, date4, date5};
    Label[] description = {description1, description2, description3, description4, description5};
    Label[] percipitation = {percipitation1, percipitation2, percipitation3, percipitation4, percipitation5};
    Label[] temp = {temperature1, temperature2, temperature3, temperature4, temperature5};
    ImageView[] images = {img1, img2, img3, img4, img5};

    for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        weather = days[i].getWeather()[0];
        String date = days[i].getDate();
        String dateFormat = date.substring(5, 7) + "." + date.substring(8, 10);
        dates[i].setText(dateFormat);
        Image image = new Image("WeatherIcons/png/001-windy-2.png");
        images[i].setImage(image);
        images[i].setFitHeight(50);
        images[i].setPreserveRatio(true);
        String des = weather.getDescription();
        double tempMax = weather.getMaxTemp();
        double tempMin = weather.getMinTemp();
        double percip = weather.getPrecipitation();
        temp[i].setText(tempMax + "\\" + tempMin);
        percipitation[i].setText(Double.toString(percip));
    }
}



@FXML
public void addLocationDialog() {
    Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.initOwner(borderPane.getScene().getWindow());
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("newLocationDialog.fxml"));
    try {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(loader.load());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.printf("New Item Dialog didn't load.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        NewLocationController controller = loader.getController();
        Location location = controller.newLocation();
        location.updateWeather();
    }
}

@FXML
public void forecastDetails(Event event) {
    System.out.println(event.getEventType().getName());
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
    button.getId();
}
```

}

And here is that FXML file associated with `Controller`. Note that all the VBoxes are pretty much the same and not following the DRY principle.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <center>
        <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" alignment="TOP_CENTER" hgap="50" prefHeight="400.0" vgap="30" gridLinesVisible="true">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="15"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="15"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="15"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="15"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="15"/>
            </columnConstraints>

            <VBox fx:id="forecast1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                <Label fx:id="date1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font></Label>
                <ImageView fx:id="img1"/>
                <Label fx:id="description1"/>
                <Label fx:id="temperature1"/>
                <Label fx:id="percipitation1"/>
                <Button fx:id="details1" text="Details" onAction="#forecastDetails"/>
            </VBox>

            <VBox fx:id="forecast2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                <Label fx:id="date2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font></Label>
                <ImageView fx:id="img2"/>
                <Label fx:id="description2"/>
                <Label fx:id="temperature2"/>
                <Label fx:id="percipitation2"/>
                <Button fx:id="details2" text="Details" onAction="#forecastDetails"/>
            </VBox>

            <VBox fx:id="forecast3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                <Label fx:id="date3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font></Label>
                <ImageView fx:id="img3"/>
                <Label fx:id="description3"/>
                <Label fx:id="temperature3"/>
                <Label fx:id="percipitation3"/>
                <Button fx:id="details3" text="Details" onAction="#forecastDetails"/>
            </VBox>

            <VBox fx:id="forecast4" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                <Label fx:id="date4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font></Label>
                <ImageView fx:id="img4"/>
                <Label fx:id="description4"/>
                <Label fx:id="temperature4"/>
                <Label fx:id="percipitation4"/>
                <Button fx:id="details4" text="Details" onAction="#forecastDetails"/>
            </VBox>

            <VBox fx:id="forecast5" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="0" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                <Label fx:id="date5">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font></Label>
                <ImageView fx:id="img5"/>
                <Label fx:id="description5"/>
                <Label fx:id="temperature5"/>
                <Label fx:id="percipitation5"/>
                <Button fx:id="details5" text="Details" onAction="#forecastDetails"/>
            </VBox>
        </GridPane>
    </center>

    <top>
        <VBox>
            <MenuBar>
                <Menu text="Location">
                    <MenuItem text="Change Location" />
                    <MenuItem onAction="#addLocationDialog" text="Add New Location" />
                </Menu>
            </MenuBar>
            <ToolBar>
                <Button fx:id="otherLocsButton" text="Other Locations" />
                <Button fx:id="todaysWeatherButton" text="Today" />
                <Button fx:id="fiveDayButton" onAction="#fiveDayForecast" text="5 day" />
                <Button fx:id="refreshButton" onAction="#refresh" text="Refresh" />
            </ToolBar>
        </VBox>
    </top>
    <left>
        <VBox>
            <ListView fx:id="locListView" />
        </VBox>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Have you looked at tutorials on creating custom controls?  This can be accomplished in several ways.  Here is an example: https://noblecodemonkeys.com/javafx-custom-controls-and-scenebuilder/

Comment: The tutorial that taught me JavaFX left subclassing out. I did give youtube a cursory browse but I couldn't find anything about subclassing the layouts specifically. All seemed to be about JavaFX layouts in general. Think you provided looks promising though. I'm watching the  video now.

Comment: Of course this *could* be done extending an existing layout, but this is a quick and dirty approach, since the user of the class still has full access to the `children` list and could easily mess up the internals of your class by modifying that list. The better approach would be to extend `Control` and create the visual structure from the skin. This requires writing a bit more code though and makes integrating fxml much harder. Regardless of how you design the new node type, you should be able to use it as fxml element with the class name as name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

main FXML:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import sample.WeatherBox?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="294.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               <WeatherBox dateText="example1" descriptionText="description1"/>
               <WeatherBox dateText="example2" descriptionText="description2"/>
         </children></VBox>
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

WeatherBox.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<fx:root type="VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Label fx:id="date">
        <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
        </font></Label>
    <ImageView fx:id="img"/>
    <Label fx:id="description"/>
    <Label fx:id="temperature"/>
    <Label fx:id="percipitation"/>
    <Button fx:id="details" text="Details" onAction="#forecastDetails"/>
</fx:root>
```

WeatherBox.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.io.IOException;


public class WeatherBox extends VBox {

    @FXML
    private Label date;
    @FXML
    private Label description;
    @FXML
    private Label temperature;
    @FXML
    private Label percipitation;
    @FXML
    private Button details;
    @FXML
    private ImageView img;

    public WeatherBox() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("WeatherBox.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }


    @FXML
    protected void forecastDetails() {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked!");
    }


    public String getDateText() {
        return date.getText();
    }

    public void setDateText(String dateText) {
        this.date.setText(dateText);
    }

    public String getDescriptionText() {
        return description.getText();
    }

    public void setDescriptionText(String dateText) {
        this.description.setText(dateText);
    }
}
```

you have to use controller class in order to define how logic will work.

Comment: Sorry I haven't thanked you yet. Your solution was exactly what I was looking for and it worked like a charm. I suppose my main confusion why I have to load an fxml file to associate with the class and have the class function as a controller as well. Seeing it action as a solution to my problem made it all click. Thanks again!